# Transforming migration ruby code to raw SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the migration that looks like this:

```
class RemoveAdministrationResponseExportsInvalidRecords < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    AdministrationResponseExport.find_each do |are|
      are.destroy if SurveyResultSet.where(id: are.survey_result_set_id).empty?
    end
  end
end
```

How can I write this in raw SQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM administration_response_exports WHERE survey_result_set_id IS NULL
```

depending on your SQL server, this might vary.

Rereading your question, this is wrong, expect another edit in a few minutes.